# How does the Twilio call object report prices when the call isn't finished?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

The [Twilio Call API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call) says for `price` that:

> Populated after the call is completed. May not be immediately available.

What does *"May not be immediately available?"* mean in this context? `price` set to `null`? No `price` key in the response object?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I just made a test call and the price was set to `null` before it was updated to a real figure.